# Syntax rules for `variable`

Tags: metafont

I have last printing of *MetafontBook* (8th printing, Volume C). Since that printing (and hence since all other printings), two very curious corrections appeared in [errata](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/errata):

1)

[image]

Question concerning this correction:

A *suffix* is either an empty set, or any number of `<tag>`s or `<subscript>`s in any combination (see syntax rules on p.54). So, a `<subscript>` is a subset of *suffix*. Therefore it is not clear why it is said

> suffixed or subscripted

as if they were separate properties.

2)

[image]

It is worth to put here definition of `<suffix list>`:

```
<suffix list> -> <suffix> | <suffix list>,<suffix>
```

Question concerning this correction:

What is any concrete specific example for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "suffixed" mean? Normally you would say something like "a variable with a suffix". But a `suffix` can also be `empty` according to the syntax rules, so this would mean that *every* variable is suffixed. Therefore the `suffix` rule is not the best reference for "suffixed". So we have to use an intuitive meaning of "suffixed". Now variables like `x.a` and `x[2]` appear and sometimes behave different, for example `x.a` and `x.b` are completely different, but `x[1]` and `x[2]` are much more connected. So especially after the comment

> But ‘x.k’ is
>   not the same; it is the tag ‘x’ suffixed by the tag ‘k’, not the tag ‘x’ subscripted
>   by the value of variable k.

a reader could assume that `x[k]` is not "suffixed".
So while "suffixed" alone should be enough, but that could lead to misunderstandings in some cases, so it is easier to just add "or subscripted".

An example for the suffix list problem is

```
newinternal x;
forsuffixes s = x1: show s; endfor
end;
```

This fails because `x` can not be suffixed, therefore `x1` is invalid.
Therefore `x`, which is an `internal quantity` and therefore a `variable`, is not a `suffix` because otherwise `x1` would also be a suffix and allowed in a `suffix list`.

In my opinion the problem here is that this seems to be a problem with `suffix list` rather than the `suffix` definition:
Assuming internal variables are not suffixes, then

```
newinternal x;
y.x1 = 1;
end;
```

shouldn't work either,but this is accepted by Metafont.

So the more accurate rule might be: An internal quantity *is* a suffix and Exercise 7.4 is true, but a `suffix list` is

```
<external suffix> -> <empty> | <subscript><suffix> | <external tag><suffix>
<suffix list> -> <external suffix> | <suffix list>,<external suffix>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what you mean by "here" in "it is therefore clearer to add both names here". Could you please re-phrase this sentence?

Comment: If I understood correctly, variables `a.b1`, `a.b2c1`, `a.b3 2 1` are called subscripted, and `a.1b`, `a.3b.c` are called suffixed. Is there any reason behind using the same terms to mean different things in different contexts?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I tried to reformulate the first paragraph.

Comment: Are you willing to post a bug report about the `<suffix list>` problem? (I can do it)

Comment: Moreover, not only `x<tag>` is invalid in `<suffix list>` (as said in second correction), but also `x<subscript>` is invalid (as in your first example). And `x<tag>` is valid in your second example too.

Comment: It is just said in the correction that you cannot say `x<tag>` in a `<suffix list>`. The following example does use `x<tag>` in a `<suffix list>` and it does not fail: `newinternal x; forsuffixes s = x.k: drawdot origin; endfor end`. Should the correction also say "and in body of loop"?

Answer (score 0):

*This a small addition to the accepted answer - the summary of my understanding.*

---

Correction 1):

the phrase "or subscripted" is there to add subscripted variables to "intuitive" meaning of "suffix".

The matter is that in MetaFontBook there are two meanings of the word "suffix": "general" (syntax rule on p.54) and "intuitive" (something non-empty other than subscript).

Correction 2):

the following examples with `x<tag>` and `x<subscript>` do not work:

```
newinternal x;
forsuffixes s = x.k: show s; endfor
end
```

```
newinternal x;
forsuffixes s = x[1]: show s; endfor
end
```

the following examples with `x<tag>` and `x<subscript>` work:

```
newinternal x;
y.x.k = 1;
end
```

```
newinternal x;
y.x[1] = 1;
end
```

So, second correction must be corrected not only as said in the accepted answer, but also to add "`x<subscript>`" to "`x<tag>`".